# Couchdb 100% CPU usage

Tags: couchdb

I used Couchdb to create a private NPM mirror, but I found that `beam.smp` kept my CPU usage to 100%, is there any way to make it lower, like 50%?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly limit CPU/memory usage for CouchDB, but you may tweak Replicator options to reduce their usage. Options you're interested:

- http_connections
  Defines maximum number of HTTP connections per replication. Keeping them lower reduces transfer bandwidth.

  ```
  [replicator]
  http_connections = 20
  ```
- worker_batch_size
  With lower batch sizes checkpoints are done more frequently. Lower batch sizes also reduce the total amount of used RAM memory.

  ```
  [replicator]
  worker_batch_size = 500
  ```
- worker_processes
  Amount of replication workers. Keeping them lower reduces amount of data replication handled => reduces CPU usage because of less data to process.

  ```
  [replicator]
  worker_processes = 4
  ```

Play with these options to find right combination to fit your limits.